# Is it possible to give sftp access to a user without giving him ssh access?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is it possible to give sftp access to a user without giving him ssh access?

Comment: Do you mean allow user to sftp into the machine, or sftp out of the machine from the shell?

Comment: Allow user to sftp into the machine of course ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the last parameter of the `/etc/passwd` file (on the user's line) to `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (or whatever sftp server you use). This will make it so that the logon shell for the user is the sftp-server, and that's all he can use. This requires less setup than the other answer, and it gets exactly to the point, although the option to allow scp later doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

Well, rssh is a restricted shell providing sftp access but no ssh access.

```
sudo apt-get install rssh
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/rssh $username
```

You might have to

```
sudo bash -c "echo '/usr/bin/rssh' >> /etc/shells"
```

to make it a "valid" shell.

**Update 9-13-2012 for Ubuntu 12.04**

The file, /etc/rssh.conf, has the various kinds of access commented; so, for sftp, uncomment line #10, "#allowsftp".

```
sudo -e /etc/rssh.conf
```

Change

```
#allowsftp
```

to

```
allowsftp
```

Save.

Comment: I've just updated this post for 11.10. The binary location has moved. Keep that in mind if you're using this on older versions of Ubuntu (Sorry, I don't know when it happened).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime It is useful to set umask for ftp client. To do that, create a simple script `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server-go.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0007
```

and use it in `/etc/passwd` instead.